# Migrating Oracle DB to another operating system from Red Hat Enterprise by using a disk image

Tags: redhat, migration, oracle, disk-image

I have a Red Hat Enterprise server disk image that Oracle DB is installed on it. My question is : Is it even possible to use this disk image in order to setup same DB on another Oracle supported operating system? If possible, how can it be done?

(I have no access to the mentioned Red Hat Enterprise server (because it's damaged). So I have only all disk files of previous installation on Red Hat Enterprise.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall, Oracle database files (and binary backups) are OS dependent.  You could access that DB if you dropped those disks into another Linux server, but you won't be able to utilize them on any non-Linux OS.

If you need them on a different Operating System, I'd recommend putting the disks into a different server or another Linux box, bring Oracle up, run an ASCII backup, then migrate that to your other Operating System.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have no idea about how to bring Oracle up by putting disks to into another Linux box. Is it all about oracle configuration files? Or should I use some Oracle specific programs or something. I know Linux well but I am not easy with Oracle setup.

Comment: I'm a SysAdmin, and I only dabble in being a DBA.  In DBA land, Oracle is not where I'm strongest.  If you have all of the disks from the original server, you could drop them all, OS and Data, into a new box, boot it up, and should be able to start and run things pretty cleanly.  If not, you're probably going to need some Oracle magic that is beyond my abilities.  I've seen it done, but by an experienced Oracle DBA who could work with the Oracle data files directly.